# Why can't access view.center.x / y

Tags: ios, objective-c, center

I'm just curious why can't you access view.center.x or view.center.y but you can access view.center and change it.

I wanted to write this code:

```
imgView_.center = scrollView_.center;
if (imgView_.frame.origin.x < 0) 
    imgView_.center = CGPointMake(imgView_.center.x + (imgView_.frame.size.width - self.view.frame.size.width) / 2, imgView_.center.y);
if (imgView_.frame.origin.y < 0)
    imgView_.center = CGPointMake(imgView_.center.x, imgView_.center.y + (imgView_.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height) / 2);
```

As:

```
imgView_.center = scrollView_.center;
if (imgView_.frame.origin.x < 0) 
    imgView_.center.x = imgView_.center.x + (imgView_.frame.size.width - self.view.frame.size.width) / 2;
if (imgView_.frame.origin.y < 0)
    imgView_.center.y = imgView_.center.y + (imgView_.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height) / 2;
```

I find the second way a lot more elegant, but I can't access the x and y, so I thought I'd ask if anyone knows what's Apple's reason for blocking it.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2983979/653513

Comment: or even better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2983939/653513

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See center property defined in `UIView's` `UIViewGeometry` category as below

```
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint center;
```

By declaration of center property, we have **getter & setter** methods for center property. it means **we have setter & getter method for structure not for the values inside structure**.
and Center is a `CGPoint` structure variable that has two `CGFloat` value **x and y**.

that's by we can't set directly x and y values in center property. it is similar to Frame property.

Comment: @LordZsolt besides the mixing of c and objective-c, one of the main reasons is there are calculated properties (e.g. frame) which need to be updated when you update the center property. changing a struct member directly would skip this update

Comment: I agreed with @wattson, there are some related properties that need to be update automatically on updating center & frame etc properties that why Apple hasn't given any link to set coordinates(X and Y) directly. specially you can see this in case of co-ordinates related property.

Answer (score 2):

The `UIView` property `center` is a `CGPoint` which is of type `struct` and not an ObjectiveC class.

Even though writing this

```
view.center.x = view.center.x +10;
```

looks similar to

```
CGPoint center = view.center;
center.x = center.x +10;
view.center = center;
```

they are different things.

According to the compiler `view.center` is a method call `[view center]` and `center.x` is accessing the public ivar of the struct `CGPoint`. If you write all of this in a single line

```
view.center.x = view.center.x +10;
```

compiler is unable to resolve this and throws an error `Expression is not assignable`. Reason is `view.center.x` is further resolved as function call,

```
objc_msgSend(view, @selector(center))
```

Now you are trying to modify the return value of a C function as below

```
objc_msgSend(view, @selector(center)).x = 20 //(Some value on RHS)
```

which is not meaningful as the function return value isn't stored anywhere, hence the resulting expression is not assignable.

For more information read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7074522/1407017).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In the fragment `imgView_.center.x` the `.center` is a *property* access while the `.x` is a *field* access. The type of the property is `CGPoint`, which is a structure type which is passed by *value*.

If you have a variable of type `CGPoint` you can directly assign to individual fields, e.g.:

```
CGPoint myPoint;
myPoint.x = 3;
```

However when passing a `CGPoint` value to a function or method you cannot pass just one of it's fields - it makes no sense. E.g. if you have the function:

```
void doSomething(CGPoint aPoint);
```

you could pass `myPoint`:

```
doSomething(myPoint);
```

but there is no way to say "just pass the `x` field" - what would that even mean? The function is expecting a `CGPoint`, what would passing it one coordinate mean?

When you put the fragment `imgView_.center` on the left hand side of an assignment you are just using a shorthand for calling a method. E.g.:

```
imgView_.center = myPoint; <=> [imgView_ setCenter:myPoint];
```

and just like with the function above there is no way to say "just pass the `x` field".

The key point is a property access is not a variable access, even though it is often thought of as one, but a function/method call; so you can't assign to the individual fields of a property of structure type.

On the right hand side accessing a field of a property is fine. E.g. on the rhs `imgView_.center` translates to `[imgView_ center]` - which returns a `CGPoint` *value*, and you can access a field of structure value, so on the rhs `imgView_.center.x` translates to `[imgView_ center].x` and all is OK. But note that in *both* cases (`setCenter:` and `center` methods) the methods themselves take/return a *complete* `CGPoint`.

HTH.