# Manipulating origin of a CGRect property through self. notation does not work but manipulating through ivar works

Tags: objective-c, properties, cgrect

This question is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983832/myview-frame-origin-x-value-does-not-work-but-why).  But since it does not address my issue completely, I am asking another one.

Suppose I have a `CGRect` property `myRect`.

I see that `self.myRect.origin = CGPointMake(x,y);` does not work (not assignable)
but `_myRect.origin = CGPointMake(x,y);` works.

I think it is because `self.myRect` is converted to a call to the accessor and so it does not get translated to what we want `[self setMyRect:CGRect(x,y,width,size)]`.  How does the compiler translate the `self.myRect.origin = CGPointMake(x,y);` statement?

Comment: The answers in the question you link are answers to your question as well.

Comment: Can you explain how those answers don't address your question completely? You ask "How does the compiler translate the self.myRect.origin = CGPointMake(x,y); statement?" From the accepted answer: "The "myView.frame" part equals [myView getFrame] and you get a copied CGRect frame (a C struct)
The "myView.frame.origin" gives you a CGPoint origin (also a struct) of the copied CGRect
The "myView.frame.origin.x = 25.0" gives you a CGFloat x of the origin and now you want to assign something to it and here comes the problem..."

Comment: It's not clear what information that you need is missing.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, In my case, I am just using a generic CGRect (i.e not accessing the frame property on a view).  In this case, won't self.myRect just be a getter for the property.  I.e I don't understand why this returns a copied version of the property (i.e copy of CGRect struct)?

Comment: `UIView`'s `frame` is just a `CGRect` property, too. It returns a copy because that's just how structs work. There's no difference unless you have some bizarre custom implementation of your property.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshCaswell.  Is this "return a copy" specific to structs or are there situations which behave like this.  Just to confirm, if the property is an objective-C class, then when accessing through getter, you are getting pointer to the actual object and not a copy, correct?

Comment: That's right, for an object property you get a pointer to the same object. (For comparison, you can also work with pointers to `struct`s, but that requires explicit handling.) Any non-object type is giving you a copy of the value, it's just less noticeable with, e.g., an `int`, because you don't expect to set just a part of the `int` like you do with a `struct`.